# How to connect event when tab widget is selected?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtabwidget

I am using PyQt5 to make the user interface. Now I have set up a tab widget, and I want to trigger the event at such a time when a specific tab is selected. In other words, for example, I have tab A and tab B, and I want to execute the function every time user is switching from tab A to tab B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a new tab is selected `currentChanged(int index)` signal of the `QTabWidget` is emitted. Just connect that signal to some slot and check the index of the newly selected tab which is passed as argument.